# How can i print my values out of my array

Tags: php, arrays

How can i print my values out of my array if there is less than 20min between them?

```
This is my foreach for myArray:

     foreach ($cooltransactions as $key=>$value)
{
$array[$key] = array('cardid' => $cooltransactions[$key]['cardid'],'created' => strtotime($cooltransactions[$key]['created']));     
 }
$newArray=array();
$i=0;
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
       $id=$array[$k]['cardid'];
       $time=$array[$k]['created'];
       foreach($array as $k1=>$v1){
          if($k<$k1){
             if($array[$k1]['cardid']==$id){
                 if(compare($time,$array[$k1]['created'])){
                     $newArray[$i]['cardid']=$id;
                     $newArray[$i]['created']=date('d-m-y H:i:s', $time['created']);
                     $i++;
                 }
             }
          }
       }
    }

  function compare($firsttime, $secondtime){
     $interval = $firsttime-$secondtime;
     $dif=round(abs($interval) / 60);
     if ($dif < 2 || $dif < -2 ) {
        return true;
     }
  }
```

print_r($newArray);

This is what i get:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [cardid] => 56324  [created] => 01-01-70 01:00:00)
[1] => Array ( [cardid] => 56324  [created] => 01-01-70 01:00:00) 
[2] => Array ( [cardid] => 21352 [created] => 01-01-70 01:00:00) 
[3] => Array ( [cardid] => 21352 [created] => 01-01-70 01:00:00)
)
```

But this is the output i want:

```
Array  ( 
    [1] => Array ( [Cardid] => 21352 [created] => 02-02-13 11:11:41 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [Cardid] => 21352 [created] => 02-02-13 10:59:48 )     
  )
```

Comment: @M42: I have tried different ways to solve it but without success.

Comment: you want to know how compare the dates or how to iterate and confront the ids?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking to split the array on condition, So you can use a foreach and set a temp variable with first one and iterate it and then check time of current node with temp value with the help of if statement.

Comment: Yes, im thinking something very similar to that. But im not sure about how to write the code for it

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
 $cooltransactions=Array ( 
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 56324, 'created' => '11-02-13 15:36:32' ),
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 56324, 'created' => '11-02-13 15:08:51' ),         
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 42683, 'created' => '10-02-13 13:42:24' ), 
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 21352, 'created' => '02-02-13 11:11:41' ), 
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 21352, 'created' => '02-02-13 11:11:41' ),
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 74124, 'created' => '02-02-13 11:02:53' ), 
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 21352, 'created' => '02-02-13 10:59:48' ) 
 );

foreach ($cooltransactions as $key=>$value)
{
$array[$key] = array('Cardid' => $cooltransactions[$key]['Cardid'],
                     'created' => strtotime($cooltransactions[$key]['created'])
                    );     
 }
$newArray=array();
$i=0;
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    if(isset($array[$k])){
       $id=$array[$k]['Cardid'];
       $time=$array[$k]['created'];
        echo $time.'<br>';
       foreach($array as $k1=>$v1){
          if($k<$k1){
             if($array[$k1]['Cardid']==$id){
                 echo '2 fields with the same id have been detected: id='.$id.'</br>'; 
                 if(compare($time,$array[$k1]['created'])){
                     $newArray[$i]['Cardid']=$id;
                     $newArray[$i]['created']=date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $array[$k1]['created']);
                     unset($array[$k1]);
                     $i++;
                 }
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
echo '<br>FINAL ARRAY:<br>';
var_dump($newArray);


  function compare($firsttime, $secondtime){
     $interval = $firsttime-$secondtime;
     $dif=round(abs($interval) / 60);
     echo 'This fields have the same id: the difference in minutes is: '.$dif.' </br>';
     if ($dif < 20 || $dif < -20 ) {
        return true;
     }
  }
```

1297629392
2 fields with the same id have been detected: id=56324
This fields have the same id: the difference in minutes is: 28
1297627731
1266086544
1013616701
2 fields with the same id have been detected: id=21352
This fields have the same id: the difference in minutes is: 0
2 fields with the same id have been detected: id=21352
This fields have the same id: the difference in minutes is: 12
1013616173

FINAL ARRAY:
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Cardid"]=> int(21352) ["created"]=> string(19) "2002-02-13 11:11:41" } [1]=> array(2) { ["Cardid"]=> int(21352) ["created"]=> string(19) "2002-02-13 10:59:48" } }

Comment: ok i can't test it now, so probably there are going to be some mistakes, but it should be something like this.. tell me what goes wrong with it so i can fix it ;)

Comment: It crashes hen is use this:
    foreach($myArray as $k=>$v){
       $id=$myArray[$k].['Cardid'];
       $time=$myArray[$k].['created'];
       foreach($myArray as $k1=>$v1){
          if($k!=$k1){
             if($myArray[$k1]['Cardid']==$id)
             {
              print_r("test");
             }
          }
       }
    }

Comment: I think there is something wrong with  $id=$array[$k].['Cardid'];
       $time=$array[$k].['created'];

Comment: yes i'm testing and fixing it give me a sec :) remove the points between ][

Comment: it reaches the echo 'ok' now when needed. Try to adapt the second piece of code i posted and let me know.

Comment: there most be something wrong with this :  $interval = date_diff($firsttime, $secondtime);
     $dif = $interval->format('%i');

Comment: in which format are the dates in your array? they need to be datetime to be compared. This is what i got as output with my test array 56324 - 2011-02-13 00:00:00 -----(0--0)(0--1)-if1-compare--dif-0--ok56324 - 2011-02-13 00:00:00 -----(1--0)(1--1). You can see one 'ok' as it's supposed to do.

Comment: I just added this to my foreach: foreach ($cooltransactions as $key)
{
   $myArray[] = array(
   'Cardid' => $key['Cardid'],
   'created' => date('d-m-y H:i:s', $key['created'])   );     
 }

Comment: created has to be new DateTime($key['created'])

Comment: It still only reaches to       echo 'compare';

Comment: it does not like  $interval = date_diff($firsttime, $secondtime);

Comment: are you using an old version of php? maybe < 5?

Comment: it works to me with this data. $cooltransactions[0]['Cardid']=56324;

$cooltransactions[0]['created']='11-02-13 15:36:32';
$cooltransactions[1]['Cardid']=56324;

$cooltransactions[1]['created']='11-02-13 15:08:51'; But it's really difficult to know what happens if you don't tell me the errors you are getting. If you don't get any error try adding this on top of your page: ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('error_log', 'my_file.log');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 'On');

Comment: i also added the code here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4ng-wz8 . you should be able to see that it works.

Comment: I am getting this now: 2 fields with the same id have been detected: id=
#compare:#This fields have the same id: the difference in minutes is: 2370518699

Comment: wow that's a big difference. What do you have in your original array??

Comment: Cool Transaction is my original array. myArray is a new array. The reason I made a new array was that it contained fewer values ​​than cooltransactions. Otherwise, they are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes but i mean what's the difference between my cooltransactions array and yours? With the data i posted and that  you can check here -> http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4ng-wz8 it works, so probably your imputs are different from mine.

Comment: Your input you have given me as an example. How can you do so it fits my expected output?

Comment: i dont' really get your desired output. with id 56324 there is a bigger difference than 20 minutes (28mins), but then with id 21352 it is smaller (12mins). Still you're printing both. Which one is the right one? By the way here is the last update to have some data in a new array to output. (i also posted the output it's giving)

Comment: So what's the output with the last code i posted? it should be like you asked: 2 fields with the same id have been detected: id=56324 This fields have the same id: the difference in minutes is: 28 2 fields with the same id have been detected: id=21352 This fields have the same id: the difference in minutes is: 12

FINAL ARRAY: array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Cardid"]=> int(21352) ["created"]=> string(17) "02-02-13 10:59:48" } }

Comment: Your code works, but it does not check the date. It only print everything out.

Comment: can you paste your output please?

Comment: Arrrh @Coslu.. Sorry i posted my question wrong :/ My output for myArray looks like this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [Cardid] => 21352 [created] => 1360848720 )

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [Cardid] => 56324 [created] => 1360848720 )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Cardid] => 56324 [created] => 1360848742 )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Cardid] => 21352 [created] => 1360848759 )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Cardid] => 21352 [created] => 1360848759 )

Comment: i think it's because you changed my code and you're printing timestamps! i edited this line $newArray[$i]['created']=date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $time); (check the above code). Are you doing this 'created' => strtotime($cooltransactions[$key]['created']) when you create the $array array?

Comment: you should maybe post the code you re using. If you're printing timestamps you surely changed something. At the beginning the times are stored in strings, then you have to convert them with strtotime to be able to compare them. Then you can convert it back to a string to put it in the new array and show it.

Comment: you are first doing 'created' =>  date('d-m-y H:i:s', $key['created']));     and then 'created' => strtotime($myArray[$key]['created']) to the same value. The error is coming because you are creating that $myarray at the beginning and making an extra time conversion.

Comment: there are multiple istances of cardid not just 2. I updated my code to fix this problem by unsetting the already found ids.

Comment: sorry there was a little mistake. i reupdated it and i get: array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Cardid"]=> int(21352) ["created"]=> string(19) "2002-02-13 11:11:41" } [1]=> array(2) { ["Cardid"]=> int(21352) ["created"]=> string(19) "2002-02-13 10:59:48" } }

Comment: Your code is good an seems to be right, but i am having problems with my "created"

Comment: what do you have inside your $cooltransactions[$key]['created'] fields? can you write a var_dump of that array? If my code works why do you change it? ;P

Comment: This is not right? This fields have the same id: the difference in minutes is: 3710108940

Comment: the date you are getting as output is: Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing instances in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), 1 January 1970. So 01-01-70 01:00:00 means that there is something wrong in  your dates, or that you are doing something wrong with my code. Here it works perfectly http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4ng-wz8

Comment: What if you put this in your code?     [0] => Array ( [cardid] => 56324  [created] => 1360781709 )
    [1] => Array ( [cardid] => 56324  [created] => 1202923325 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [cardid] => 21352 [created] => 1894496713 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [cardid] => 21352 [created] => 1894496713 )

Comment: I just made it work @CosLu :), but in your final array, you only print CardId 21352 one time. I want it to print out more if the same cardid is within 20 minutes.

Comment: just add inside this if(compare($time,$array[$k1]['created'])){ the code to insert also the other array fields in the newarray. Can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=Array ( 
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 56324, 'created' => '11-02-13 15:36:32' ),
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 56324, 'created' => '11-02-13 15:08:51' ),         
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 42683, 'created' => '10-02-13 13:42:24' ), 
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 21352, 'created' => '02-02-13 11:11:41' ), 
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 74124, 'created' => '02-02-13 11:02:53' ), 
    Array ( 'Cardid' => 21352, 'created' => '02-02-13 10:59:48' ) 
 );

function filter_rows($rows)
{
   $cards=array();
   foreach($rows as $row)
   {
     $cards[$row['Cardid']][]=$row['created'];
   }

   $res=array();

   foreach($cards as $cardid=>$card_trns)
   {
      for($i=1,$ms=count($card_trns);$i<$ms;$i++)
      {
        $d1=new DateTime($card_trns[$i]);
        $d0=new DateTime($card_trns[$i-1]);
        $di=$d1->diff($d0,true);
        $diff_min=$di->format('%i');
        if($diff_min<=20)
        {
           $res[]=array('Cardid'=>$cardid, 'created'=>$card_trns[$i]);
           $res[]=array('Cardid'=>$cardid, 'created'=>$card_trns[$i-1]);
        }
      }
   }
   return $res;
}

print_r(filter_rows($arr));
```

Comment: something wroing with 

 $di=$d1->diff($d0,true);
        $diff_min=$di->format('%i');
        if($diff_min<=20)
        {
           $res[]=array('Cardid'=>$cardid, 'created'=>$card_trns[$i]);
           $res[]=array('Cardid'=>$cardid, 'created'=>$card_trns[$i-1]);
        }